# Name of unusual power adaptor plug

Tags: ac, output, adapter

I'm trying to find out if this kind of power plug for my laptop has a name, so that I can google for it more successfully.

I haven't ever seen any other like it, with its 4 pin connectors.

Does this style of plug have a name?

[image: plug_end_on]
[image: plug_side_on]
[image: power_pack]

Comment: Try 4-pin [mini-DIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini-DIN_connector).

Comment: If you're looking for replacement unit, searching for "liteon pa-1331-90" will suffice.

Comment: @AndrewMorton  Thank you for helping.  I have indeed found some of these units for sale.  Meanwhile "4-pin mini DIN" (and variant searches) returns many various results. The closest, I think, is this one https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/industrial-circular-connectors/1115756/

Comment: You're welcome :) Please be aware that the plug you linked to is a locking one, rather than a non-locking one as shown in the question.